# Android Share Intent file format not supported

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I am trying to share an image from my drawable folder. It worked before but now for some reason whenever I try to share I will select the person to share it to, and it will give me an message that says: "file format is not supported". For some reason I can't share it with Whatsapp, but I can share it with another app like snapchat. So I know it is getting the correct image.

Here is my sharing code:

```
Uri imageUri;
imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "image" + String.valueOf(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1));
//imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + R.drawable.image1);
Log.d("Sharing", "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "image" + String.valueOf(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1));
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Ha Ha! Check out this picure I got with todays date! Download the app: http://www.google.com");
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Here is an error I got from the logs, but I am not using an ArrayList to share.

```
W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected ArrayList but value was a android.net.Uri$StringUri.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

And what the Log.d prints out:

```
D/Sharing: android.resource://com.trommelen.okke.scheurkalender/drawable/image155
```

Comment: please share what that log prints out

Comment: @Neil Added the log

Comment: Thanks but I actually meant this line. Log.d("Sharing", "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "image" + String.valueOf(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1));

Comment: @Neil added the log

Comment: Do you have that image in your drawable folder?

Comment: @AshishTiwari yes I do, I also tried to get the image directly from the drawable folder without getting it dynamicly.

Comment: Did you try like this:

    `imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_lock));`

Comment: @AshishTiwari I don;t think the problem is getting the image, I think the problem is that the `EXTRA_STREAM` needs an `Arraylist` for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by adding a bitmap and add the permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the Manifest

```
Bitmap imgBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(),R.drawable.image1);
String imgBitmapPath=Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),imgBitmap,"title",null);
Uri imgBitmapUri=Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath);
```

then add the `imgBitmapUri` as extra stream.

Comment: You may wish to make this answer more readable (the code looks rather bad in this form).

Comment: Does this compile? I'm not an Android developer but `getContetResolver` looks wrong. Just like `androi.permission`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see these mistakes, I just fixed them.